# Why predicted values differ among methods?

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, multilevel-analysis, residuals

I am using the dataset Orthodont from nlme to simplify my example.

```
library(nlme)
fm1 <- lme(distance ~ age + Sex, random = list(Subject = ~ 1+age), data = Orthodont)
```

First, I created the predicted values based on the traditional package stats:

```
# Method 1: Using stats package
newdata<-expand.grid(age=unique(Orthodont$age),Sex=unique(Orthodont$Sex))
newdata$fitted<-c(stats::predict(fm1, newdata = newdata, level = 0))
```

Second, I obtained the residuals manually and averaged them:

```
# Method 2: Extracting information from model
d<-data.frame(age=Orthodont$age,Sex=Orthodont$Sex,distance=Orthodont$distance)
d$residuals<-residuals(fm1)
d$fitted<- fitted.values(fm1)
newdata2<- aggregate(fitted ~ age+Sex, d, FUN = function(x) mean(x, na.rm=T))
```

The residuals from method 1 differed from method 2:

```
merge(newdata, newdata2, by=c("age","Sex"))
```

I am guessing that the problem is the average of the extracted residuals. How could I obtain the corrected predicted values using the manual approach?